# Converting xml to json with json.net

Tags: c#, xml, json, windows-runtime, json.net

I try to convert my XML String to Json with Json.Net

In the Json.Net [Documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/) it says that i have to use this code to convert xml to json:

```
string xml = @"<person id='1'>
         <name>Alan</name>
        <url>http://www.google.com</url>
         <role>Admin1</role>
     </person>";

 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
 doc.LoadXml(xml);

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
```

But in my Windows 8 App i can't find the XmlDocument class neither the SerializeXmlNode.

I tried it with these classes and functions:

```
 var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
 XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();
 xdoc = XDocument.Load(result);
 // Parse the JSON Radio data
 string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(xdoc);
 var radios = JsonArray.Parse(result);
```

But i get the following error:

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Illegal characters in path.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

In result i have the correct xml loaded. Starting with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<item>...</item>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `XDocument.Parse` instead of `XDocument.Load` which loads the xml from an url

Comment: thanks this solved the problem. i can load the xml now :) I'll accept the answer as soon as i can.